# Unicode in sqsh connecting to MSSQL (or alternatives)

Tags: sql-server, linux, utf-8, sqsh

I have a MSSQL database, which contains Unicode (utf8) data. My workstation is linux (currently Ubuntu) and looking for a tool to work with mssql database I found SQSH.
The problem is - when I select data in the sqsh console I get jibberish instead of unicode characters. Using switch "-J utf8" or "-J utf-8" didn't change anything.

The question is - how to set up sqsh to work with utf-8 data?

If it is not possible, do you know any alternative tools usable from linux for work with mssql databases filled with utf-8 data. I need to execute all kinds of T-SQL, run previsously prepared SQL script files, and pipe out results for processing afterwards. A good GUI (open source) could also be used, not limited to shell clients.

Comment: Considering you say you're storing utf-8 data in SQL Server, I *assume* you're using SQL Server 2019 preview?

Comment: Unicode means UTF16 on Windows and SQL Server. Unicode text is stored in `nvarchar` fields. It works without any issue - SO is an ASP.NET web site that uses SQL Server. UTF8 support was added only for bulk import/export in the latest versions. UTF8 as a varchar encoding *will* be added in SQL Server 2019, which is currently in preview

Comment: Have you tried [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-2017) or [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017)? Unfortunate name, but that's the cross-platform developer IDE for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Are you using freetds with sqsh?  If you are, edit your freetds.conf to set the charset.

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/localization.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Azure Data Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017) to avoid data troubleshooting issue. it is a great SSMS alternative for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you need command line tool I suggest to use official **[sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-2017#ubuntu)** from mssql-tools. 
It is available for all major Linux distributions including Ubuntu.

[Connecting with sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-sqlcmd?view=sql-server-2017)

---

Another shell tool is **[mssql-cli](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2017/12/12/try-mssql-cli-a-new-interactive-command-line-tool-for-sql-server/)**

> Features
>
> Mssql-cli is a new and interactive command line tool that provides the
>   following key enhancements over sqlcmd in the Terminal environment:
>
> - T-SQL IntelliSense
> - Syntax highlighting
> - Pretty formatting for query results, including Vertical Format
> - Multi-line edit mode
> - Configuration file support

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems it has nothing to do with charchters encoding, but the problem was there are control character, unprintable characters, in the script.

I removed them from the sql script and everything works fine.